# Run shell script from python

Tags: python

I am trying to run a shell script from a python script using the following:

```
from subprocess import call
call(['bash run.sh'])
```

This gives me an error, but I can successfully run other commands like:

```
call(['ls'])
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should separate arguments:

```
call(['bash', 'run.sh'])
call(['ls','-l'])
```

Comment: Is there a way to run .sh scripts in Python on Windows?

Answer (score 5):

```
from subprocess import call
import shlex
call(shlex.split('bash run.sh'))
```

You want to properly tokenize your command arguments.  `shlex.split()` will do that for you.

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

> Note shlex.split() can be useful when determining the correct
>   tokenization for args, especially in complex cases:

Answer (score 3):

When you call `call()` with a `list`, it expects every element of that list to correspond to a command line argument.
In this case it is looking for `bash run.sh` as *the* executable with spaces and everything as a single string.

Try one of these:

```
call("bash run.sh".split())
call(["bash", "run.sh"])
```